# Populate Cell with Next Follow-Up Date after Today()

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm working in GoogleSheets and hoping to select the follow-up date most immediately following Today, and place that date in a cell which corresponds to the name in Column A of that same row.

[image]

My intuition tells me it has something to do with =HLOOKUP and =Today() functions, but beyond that I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Tim. Any ideas on solutions?

Comment: Links to external resources in a question are frowned upon as if the link resource is gone the question will no longer make any sense. Can you please edit your question so that it shows what you want in the question itself? If you want tomorrows date =TODAY()+1

Comment: Not so much looking for Today()+1 as how to integrate that into an HLOOKUP function. About the link, it's never been an issue for me before.

Comment: So you are trying to find the Next Follow-Up date after today for each client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using you exact sample data: enter into B13 and fill down

```
=INDEX(B2:N2,1,MATCH(TODAY()+1,B2:N2,1)+1)
```

Comment: A more elegant solution than mine.  You might want to add some explanation of how to use it and how it works though ;-)

Comment: Thanks to you both!